# How to replace the links http to https

Tags: redirect, https

I have a few http URLs in my website that aren't being converted to https.

script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"

src='data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg%20xmlns=%22http://www.w3.org/2000/svg%22%20viewBox=%220%200%20210%20140%22%3E%3C/svg%3E'

How to convert this links from http to https?

Comment: For the first one you'll have to find where this is enqueued by a plugin or theme: it's not WordPress core. Try grepping all of your WordPress files including plugins and themes for 'htm5shim'.

Comment: I think the second one is OK: it's an XML namespace, not something your users will actually load.

Comment: When i run my site  https://www.jitbit.com/sslcheck/ it will show unsecured content, I can see this src links only as in http . The  site url is https://www.dhyanit.com

Comment: For the script, yes, and you'll need to find that code that's enqueuing that to fix it. But I don't think it should report unsecured content for the xmlns in an SVG data URI. Relevant question on StackOverflow: [Does svg xmlns attribute value require a protocol? Can it be https or relative?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39960017/243245)

Comment: Hi Rup, Thanks for the support. The issues successfully fixed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wordpress : To load all asset files coming from HTTP to HTTPS?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/108175/wordpress-to-load-all-asset-files-coming-from-http-to-https)